# Compact disk software and PlayOnLinux

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I am trying to install a software that came with my USB interface on PlayOnLinux. I am not getting very far. How do I install software that’s on a compact disk on Linux? Oh I am using Ubuntu 13.4 by the way.

Comment: Please read [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install some packages in wine, try wine explorer.exe and It would show you an file manager. Then you can double-click the installation media (EXE).

If you want to install some packages in your OS (Linux, probably Ubuntu), Try deb or yum to install the package.

Answer (score -1):

For .deb I use gdebi. You can install this program from the Softwarecenter. Afterwards you have a rightclick option - open with - "Install with Gdebi", or something like this.

Comment: Did you read question? It is about PlayOnLinux.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not really clear, which type of software he wants to install.