# Tally ERP 9 Need native solution for UBUNTU

Tags: installation

i have install Tally ERP 9 on ubuntu using wine. but its pretty slow and facing lot of problem. your forum suggested to us VM ware or other virtual os but that goes slow after lot of data entry in tally and also cannot use in full screen.

We most do Tally and other works together like checking document while using tally and lot more work.. for that every time switch to win7 to ubuntu is headache. please provide some native solution for Tally. as this program is used by over 90% of Small and medium entreprise in india. if this works well then ubuntu will boom in domestic business market in india. i hope you will provide any further solution for this.

Thanks
Jitendra

Comment: The Wine App DB says, that [Tally 9 works on Wine 1.7.4](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=18517&iTestingId=81652) except for Excel export. Maybe you just need to upgrade your Wine version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows software or games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a request for developing a new software.

Answer (score 1):

Install Oracle Virtual Box, and then Install Windows XP ,then tally ERP,  it will be fast.

Otherwise there is no native solution for tally. Ask tally to provide packages for linux also. If you are using Legal Copy then you can ask them to develop. More queries to them, more they will think about it.

GNU Cash is a nice alternative but most of  Indian people hardly want to try something new. They usually get stuck with what they are using.

Tally ERP is a nice software suitable mostly for Indian needs. So only option left so far to use Virtualbox.