# How can I run exe files in wine?

Tags: wine

I can't seem to run an exe file in ubuntu 12.04.  I don't have anything configured, and I'm a complete novice to Wine, so put it in layman terms.

Comment: Can you give a bit of background to what you have tried and what you happened or didn't happen. This will make it easier for someone to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games

Comment: I don't understand the down-votes. 
This is a legit question and I've come here because it's the number 1 result when searching on Google for the query: "wine launch .exe"

Answer (score 1):

In general, you run an application with:

```
wine /path/to/program.exe
```

In general, with many applications, you run the installation .exe and it installs to your wine directory , ~/.wine

In general, after you install an application in wine you will then have a launcher or a wine menu (depends a bit on your interface (kde).

For additional information see: [this Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1180031) which links to basic info on WINE and a primer you may find useful, as well as the [official Ubuntu website post on WINE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine).

For testing, I'd suggest starting with a well known 32-bit app, such as the Windows version of 7-Zip, which has a Platinum rating in the [WINE Apps db](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1487).

Comment: I would suggest you give some general advice, and reference that link for further information.

Comment: I did what it said, but I still can't get the .exe file to work.

Comment: [UPDATE] I get this message when I try to run it: fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100

C:\users\ethan\Temp\1b59.tmp>java -classpath .;./jshortcut-0.4-oberzalek.jar;./commons-io.jar; Instal 
File not found.


C:\users\ethan\Temp\1b59.tmp>pause 
Press any key to continue...

Comment: @K7AAY It's a Minecraft mod creator that I got online.  It doesn't have a rating as far as I know.

Comment: And, which kinda Java does it depend on? Java apps sometimes require specific types of Java, and from the error message, that's what it looks like.

Comment: @K7AAY JDK Java 7, which is what I have.

Comment: TY, but over my head.