# Slingbox tv streamer

Tags: video-streaming

As a newbie to Ubuntu, I have tried to access my slingbox tv sender, but a message comes back from slingbox saying that this OS (Ubuntu0 is not supported!
Does anyone know a way round this? or will I have to go back to Windows?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately as i checked this link,the Slingbox hasn't a specific player for Ubuntu :

> http://www.slingbox.com/get/press-downloads

But you can install `wine` on ubnutu and play your Slingbox player in it .please go through :

> [How can I install Windows software or games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)