# Windows Games how do i code in to play on linux

Tags: windows, games

I Really want to switch to linux but i own a crap ton of windows games. and i would want to play them on my machine. is there anyway possible to play the newest titles on said ubuntu machine? like what code would i need and how do i implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com), or [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/about/), for quite a lot of Windows games.

There is a list of supported games for PlayOnLinux [here](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/supported_apps-1-0.html), and a help page for it can be found [here](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/manual.html).

There is pretty much the same question as yours [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games/262123#262123), which may be of help.

Comment: i understand that but im asking how do i code it in im willing to learn lol.

Comment: @DustyFox: download wine source code at http://wiki.winehq.org/GitWine, and study it. It's just [2.5 millions of lines of code](http://www.ohloh.net/p/wine), piece of cake.

Comment: Okay i see. but how does this make me learn how to code it. im just studying and its pretty jiberish to me. and i evne know java and html lol.

Comment: HTML and Java sadly is probably not enough for a program to copy Windows things - even Wine is not enough for quite a few Windows programs, but that is what Wine is for. As Rmano sort of said, at 2,560,433 lines of code, there is rather a lot of code in Wine. Also, as [this](http://www.ohloh.net/p/wine/analyses/latest/languages_summary) demonstrates, 97% of it is written in C, only 1.5% is in HTML, and 3% is in [Java*Script*](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_javascript.xml). The wine Git repository means you can create your own version of Wine, with your own preferences and bug fixes.