# Will my software and soundcards work in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, soundcard

If I change to Linux Ubuntu will my old SoundBlaster soundcard and some of my software that I used with windows XP still work?

Comment: @Danatela I don't think so, at least not for the driver(s) part, that seems to be the main part of the question. I am not sure I should include the Wine part, or just link to the existing answer on that :)

Comment: @Jacob, in any case the link should be useful :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Sound-HOWTO/x96.html) site, at least SoundBlaster 1.0, SoundBlaster 16, SoundBlaster 16ASP, SoundBlaster 2.0, SoundBlaster 32, SoundBlaster 64, SoundBlaster AWE32, SoundBlaster AWE64, SoundBlaster Live!, SoundBlaster PCI 128   SoundBlaster PCI 512, SoundBlaster Pro, SoundBlaster Vibra16, SoundBlaster Vibra16X are supported.

Many times, older hardware works perfectly under Linux/Ubuntu.

Windows software does not run on Linux, unless it is through Wine (a "compatibility layer capable of running Windows applications") in many cases, but definitely not all. You will find more detailed information [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&sTitle=Browse%20Applications&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=true) to find if your application(s) will work through Wine.

At the same time, I should remark that in almost all cases the Linux equivalents of WIndows programs work perfectly and the exchange of files between Linux and Windows is no problem at all in these days. Many (nearly all) of the document formats are even the same.

There is an extensive post on Askubuntu about running software [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games).

Answer (score 0):

I had no problem at all with my sound cards in Ubuntu. I can confirm it works fine with SoundBlaster Live! and SoundBlaster X-Fi. However, it has less options so do not hold your breath.

And to the software: there exist [Cedega](http://transgaming.com/), [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/%E2%80%8E) and [Crossover](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover-linux/) which use different relations with Wine. If the Wine itself cannot run specific software, you should try one of them.