# Executable on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: executable

I'm running ubuntu 14.04. how can i open an executable? I've already tried to follow the instructions on other posts about the same subject, although they're all about previous versions of ubuntu, and the instructions are too complex or me anyway. I know nothing about ubuntu, because I am new to it. Could you please explain it to me, plain and simple, how to execute a file?

thank you!

Comment: This is pretty detailed description - [How can I install Windows software or games?](http://askubuntu.com/a/262123)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows software or games?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Answer (score 1):

Full edit:
Right click the executable file and select `Properties`.
Then, click `Permissions`.
The last step is to check `Allow executing file as a program`.

Comment: already done that. still have the same problem. yes I mean .exe file, but not necessarily, it can be a jar file, for example. each time I try to open it I receive the message "The file '/home/swan/Downloads/Adobe Acrobat XI Pro 11.0.6 Multilanguage [ChingLiu]/AcrobatPro_11_Web_WWMUI.exe' is not marked as executable.  If this was downloaded or copied from an untrusted source, it may be dangerous to run.  For more details, read about the executable bit."

Comment: That's another thing. I'll change the post.

Comment: I've done that - Right click the executable file and select Properties. Then, click Permissions. The last step is to check Allow executing file as a program. - but then the only thing that happens is nothing. no error, no message, no file opening. I double click on it and it just doesn't react

Comment: Open terminal and type-in

>wine /home/swan/Downloads/Adobe Acrobat XI Pro 11.0.6 Multilanguage [ChingLiu]/AcrobatPro_11_Web_WWMUI.exe

Comment: the ">" is part of what I must type? anyway i tried both ways. here's what i got:    swan@Cisne:~$  >wine /home/swan/Downloads/Adobe Acrobat XI Pro 11.0.6 Multilanguage [ChingLiu]/AcrobatPro_11_Web_WWMUI.exe
bash: /home/swan/Downloads/Adobe: No such file or directory                                                             
swan@Cisne:~$ wine /home/swan/Downloads/Adobe Acrobat XI Pro 11.0.6 Multilanguage [ChingLiu]/AcrobatPro_11_Web_WWMUI.exe
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/swan/.wine'
wine: cannot find '/home/swan/Downloads/Adobe'

Comment: The path name contains spaces. Enclose it in double quotes like this: `wine "/home/swan/Downloads/Adobe Acrobat XI Pro 11.0.6 Multilanguage" `

Answer (score -1):

go to ubuntu software center and install the "wine Windows Program Loader" .  then open the file with this program. let me know if it worked for you.