# Executable program files

Tags: command-line

I have booted Ubuntu 16.04.1 Desktop from a DVD and am attempting to run a wallet program, specifically for Linux, that I downloaded from a website. I'm intimately familiar with the program as it runs on Windows and OSX. For Windows, the program is a simple .exe file (nexxuscoin-qt.exe) that is typically placed on the Desktop and run from there. For OSX, it is a simple .dmg file (nexxuscoin-qt.dmg) that is typically placed in the Applications folder and run from there.

For Linux it is a file without an extension, however the system identifies it as an executable file. It will not run. I'm completely new to Linux. I know there are other Linux users of this particular wallet program because they show up on the blockchain explorer. Must I fully install Ubuntu in order for a program to run or is there something else I'm missing? I have tried checking the box "allow executing file as program" but it makes no difference. The actual filename is: `nexxuscoin-qt` and as it's downloaded it's compressed. So, I unzipped it with Archive Manager. No matter what I try, it won't run.

I see mention of certain commands as well as references to libraries but I have no idea what they mean. As I said, I'm completely new to Linux. I obtained a space computer to install Ubuntu on with the provision that I backup certain document files before repartitioning the hard drive, which currently contains Windows XP. This will NOT be a dual-boot system. It will be 100% Ubuntu and yes, I have verified that I am attempting to run the correct program. I can determine which operating system it is compiled for by the version number.

```
$ file nexxuscoin-qt 
nexxuscoin-qt: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=236481a719334b8d222179b17fce5e222f668c98, not stripped

$ ldd nexxuscoin-qt 
linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007ffc4cda7000) 
libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f84ee1ef000) 
libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f84edd93000) 
libdb_cxx-4.8.so => not found 
libboost_system.so.1.54.0 => not found     
libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0 => not found    
libboost_program_options.so.1.54.0 => not found 
libboost_thread.so.1.54.0 => not found
libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f84ed704000) 
libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f84ed5aa000) 
libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f84ed062000) 
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f84ecb8b000) 
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f84ec96e000) 
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f84ec5ec000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f84ec2e2000)    
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f84ec0cc000) 
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f84ebd03000) 
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f84ebafe000) 
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f84eb8ab000) 
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f84eb59a000) 
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f84eb25f000) 
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f84eb045000)
libproxy.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1 (0x00007f84eae24000) 
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f84eabfe000) 
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f84ea9a0000) 
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f84ea72f000) 
libicui18n.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.55 (0x00007f84ea2cc000) 
libicuuc.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 (0x00007f84e9f38000) 
libpcre16.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre16.so.3 (0x00007f84e9cd2000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f84e9ac9000) /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005610d73c6000)     
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f84e98c1000) 
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f84e9650000) 
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f84e942e000) 
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f84e9183000) 
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f84e8f5e000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f84e8d35000) 
libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f84e8b32000) 
libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f84e892e000) 
libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f84e8727000) 
libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f84e8524000) 
libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f84e82f5000) 
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f84e80e3000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f84e7ee0000) 
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f84e7cd9000) 
libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f84e7ad7000) 
libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f84e78be000) 
libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f84e76b8000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f84e74b2000) 
libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f84e72a3000) 
libicudata.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55 (0x00007f84e57eb000) 
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f84e55e7000) 
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f84e53e0000)
```

The program I am attempting to run is NOT a Windows .exe file. However, I figured it couldn't hurt to install **wine** and to try running the program in **wine**. Or an alternative might be to install **wine** [sudo apt-get install wine] and try to run the Windows version of this wallet program in **wine**. However, when I tried to install **wine** the installation froze after displaying what appears to be a Microsoft truetype font software agreement and the "OK" that appears at the bottom is not clickable and there is no obvious way to continue or complete the installation. I would really prefer to run the Linux version of this program if possible.

Comment: libproxy.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1 (0x00007f84eae24000)
 libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f84eabfe000)
 libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f84ea9a0000)
 libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f84ea72f000)
 libicui18n.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.55 (0x00007f84ea2cc000)
 libicuuc.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55 (0x00007f84e9f38000)
 libpcre16.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre16.so.3 (0x00007f84e9cd2000)

Comment: librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f84e9ac9000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005610d73c6000)
 libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f84e98c1000)
 libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f84e9650000)
 libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f84e942e000)
 libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f84e9183000)
 libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f84e8f5e000)

Comment: libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f84e8d35000)
 libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f84e8b32000)
 libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f84e892e000)
 libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f84e8727000)
 libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f84e8524000)
 libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f84e82f5000)
 libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f84e80e3000)

Comment: libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f84e7ee0000)
 libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f84e7cd9000)
 libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f84e7ad7000)
 libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f84e78be000)
 libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f84e76b8000)

Comment: libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f84e74b2000)
 libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f84e72a3000)
 libicudata.so.55 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55 (0x00007f84e57eb000)
 libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f84e55e7000)
 libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f84e53e0000)

Comment: will edit the post in the future. thanks @muru

Comment: eh. PLEASE don't dump a load of logs in small chunks in comments, ever. Its unreadable, impolite (cause it pings the users who have chatted) and isn't the way we do things. *And* its literally more work than editing the original post, so there's no good reason to do so.

Comment: _“For OSX, it is a simple .dmg file (nexxuscoin-qt.dmg) that is typically placed in the Applications folder and run from there.”_ Just for the record: This is simply not true. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executable on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/455347/executable-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 2):

Compiled executables usually don't have a file extension, scripts usually have the file extensions `.sh` but Linux systems don't care much about file extensions, or at least less than Windows and OS X.

Open a terminal where the file is. You can do this by right-clicking and choosing `Open in Terminal`.

Then type this:

```
./nex
```

, then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This will only work if you checked the "Allow executing file as program" box in advance (or made the file executable by other means like running `chmod +x yourfilename`).

If the program needs to be run with root privileges, use

```
sudo ./nex
```

and autocomplete.

This should not require the system to be installed.

From the output of `file nexxuscoin-qt` you have posted by now, it can be taken that you downloaded a binary for a x86-64 architecture, meaning it requires a 64-bit capable x84 CPU running a x86 64 bit operating system (commonly abbreviated to "64 bit OS" or something alike) in order to be executed.

You can easily test this by running

```
uname -a
```

whose output should end in `x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. If it doesn't, you're not running an x86 64 bit GNU Linux. If there is a `i386` in there, it means that you're running an x86 32 bit OS.