# How to install NFS mw 2 using playonlinux or wine

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I don't see the option for NFS most wanted 2 in the install menu for playonlinux.
Does that mean its not supported ?
Will it work with WINE?
Has anybody already done it?

Comment: POL (Playonlinux) uses WINE as a backend. If POL doesn't have a premade setup then noone has made one yet.

Answer (score 0):

All games tested on Wine is displayed [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&sTitle=Browse%20Applications&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=true). If its not available, it probably wont work

Answer (score 0):

Playing NFS most wanted 2 on Ubuntu is possible with Wine. You may [refer this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games) to know how.