# Play Window Games on Ubuntu

Tags: games

I have many windows games on my PC like Doom, Doom 2, Diablo, Diablo 2, Diablo 3, NFS Games, Left 4 Dead games call of Duty games, Halo games and many many more games i have in my Laptop. I just like to know if its possible to intall them and play them on Ubuntu without using Steam, im not a Steam fan at all. Because im a Hard core gamer and i dont want to change from Window 8.1 to Ubuntu if all of my games are not compatible.

Comment: Looks like you should stick with Windows on that one, or at least dual boot, probably not *all* your games will work perfect.

Comment: If you do decide to give it a go, This question has more information on using Wine or PlayOn http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games

Comment: For each game check the winehq page. It will tell you what you *can* and **can not** play using wine.

Answer (score 2):

You can install Wine (http://www.winehq.org/)

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

This programme allow you to execute Windows software in linux plateforms. Or you can use a virtual machine (with [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) for example), and to install on Windows 8 for your games.

Answer (score 1):

Most of those games do not have Linux native versions, but many work well using Wine. You can find out more about which games work in Wine and how well using the app database:

http://appdb.winehq.org/

Doom, in particular, has lots of Linux ports and can be played natively.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the games work in Ubuntu under wine. Wine is program that let's you run windows programs on Linux(ubuntu) without emulation(no CPU loss, lagging, etc.). You can check if  certain game(or program) is compatible with wine and if it possibly has some problems running on wine on [Wine HQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/). Just enter the game you want in search. I'll do it for the games you mentioned, but you can see more details by clicking on the links.

- Doom - No information
- [Doom II](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=13447) - Everything works except background music(old results)
- [Diablo](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=3498&iTestingId=72179), [Diablo II](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=315), [Diablo 3](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25953) - Everything works
- NFS work fine as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

you can run windows programs in linux via wine. install it with `sudo apt-get isntall wine1.7` and install latest Nvidia or ATI driver,Then install your games.