# lockdir.exe open in linux

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, directory, unlock

I have locked my files using lockdir.exe in my external hard drive when I had Windows 8 in my lap top. I know the password. But now I am using linux 14.04 and now I need to get those file but I cannot open it using linux. Can Anyone help me find a way to open the lockdir.exe program??

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) to open `lockdir.exe`. See [How can I install Windows software or games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Comment: I have already used wine. But it shows error and cannot open lockdir.exe

Comment: Please edit your question and give information about the error in `wine`.