# Screen resolution locked at 800x600

Tags: 14.04

I have reviewed the answers that exist.  I trialed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Novatech U50SI1 and it ran perfectly albeit slowly, so I installed it in place of Windows XP.

When I booted up 14.04 my screen resolution locked at 800x600 and I do not have the option in settings to have anything other than this resolution.

The text is therefore very large and the screen overflows so that I cannot scroll to some of the command buttons.

`Xrandr` just errors out with `"invalid resolution"`, no matter what I type (even 800x600).

When I boot from the disk the screen resolution is fine.  I think the video card for this model is SIS Mirage 3 but I am not sure how to check.  The only driver updates I have found are for windows not Ubuntu and they all have .exe files my Ubuntu install will not run.

I hope this is now clear. My question is how do I change the resolution and also run .exe programs?

Comment: what video card are you using and what error is xrandr giving you?

Comment: That's two unrelated questions. The second is answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games

Comment: To show what graphics card you are using, open the terminal and run the command: `lspci -nn | grep VGA`. The output of this command will provide sufficient information to determine what graphics driver(s) are compatible with your system, so please edit your question and add the output of `lspci -nn | grep VGA` to it, or else post the output as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going to System Settings/Software & Updates/Additional Drivers/*Selecting a driver for your video card*, assuming this was not done already. I had the same problem after installing Ubuntu and that is how i solved it.

Comment: That is a good idea .. the only problem is that it is an older PC that I inherited and I have no idea what the video card is, nor how to find out.  I suppose that I could try to contact the supplier

Comment: Assuming you're using Ubuntu 14.04 as mentioned in the original post; the menu i mentioned lists the detected video adapters and lets you select from provided drivers.

Also the top right menu/About my computer should tell you something about the graphic adapter.

Comment: Try getting the card information from the system using `lspci` or `lshw -C display`