# Hearthstone on chromebook (Samsung)

Tags: 12.04, samsung, chromebook

I've installed ubuntu with crouton (version 12.04 of ubuntu) and wonder if there's a chance I can install games like hearthstone on it, and if so, how?
I'm aware that it's not a laptop for games and such, but would be really intrested in trying it out.
The version of the chromebook is a Samsung XE503C12-K02SE

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows software or games?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Answer (score 0):

Download Game from Blizzard

```
http://dist.blizzard.com/downloads/hs-installers/a6029a1d625c79252defff3914fb6e67/retail.1/Hearthstone-Setup-enUS.exe
```

Install Wine

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install wine
```

Install Hearthstone from Play on Linux.

Source/Full Guide: http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/04/install-hearthstone-heroes-warcraft-ubuntu-wine/

Comment: But is it possible to download wine on my chromebook?

Comment: Yes you can run Windows Software with wine on chromebook

Comment: Ye, but i read something about that it was only possible for chromebooks with ARM proccesors or something, when I try "sudo apt-get install wine" it tells me: "E: Packadge 'wine' has no installation candidate"

Comment: WINE does not and will not work on the ARM Chromebook, as Windows executables are i386/x64, and WINE runs them directly (it is not an emulator). It works fine on x86-based Chromebooks using the version in the repositories. Hope this helps, If your question is answered please marked it as solved.

Comment: So there's no common apps like wine I can use or so?