# Is there any other way to play windows games on ubuntu?

Tags: sound, wine, games

I tried using wine but it makes the gameplay lag too much. I don't want to go back to windows just to play games. I love ubuntu way too much. So can anyone tell me any methods to play games on my ubuntu. Also I am not a hard core gamer. I like to play those old games like GTA Vice city and Shadowman. I don't play them on a regular basis. However I would feel more comfortable if it is available on my linux to play at any time I want.

Comment: run windows in a virtual machine

Comment: i tried that too. But the games either wont start or will be too choppy to play comfortably.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows software or games?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Comment: crossover is not free, yet fulfeatured 30 days trial is available and you may check your game is working https://www.codeweavers.com/support/wiki/linux/linuxtutorial/install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only 2 ways.

1.) Virtual Machine - Virtual Box (the free and worst thing you could use for gaming) or VMware (not free but runs circles around Virtual box in benchmarks).

2.) WINE/PlayonLinux - this is what most ppl use and it works for most everything.

if you have problems with certain programs in WINE try going to the appdp.winehq.org and looking it up. you might find information on how to make it work as some programs require you to tweak the settings a bit.

Comment: VMware Player is free (for non-commercial use), though.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a virtual machine, but aside from that it's impossible without Wine.

Answer (score 0):

Or You could use a dual boot, that way you would have two systems but completely independent and with full performances on booth.