# How can I install Microsoft Word & Excel in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

I need to install Microsoft Word & Excel in Ubuntu 14.04.
Please assist step by step as I am new to Ubuntu.

Thanks!

Comment: If it's solely for printing, have you considered trying the online versions of Word and Excel available through OneDrive?

Comment: @MatthewSteeples That is a good idea. But I dont have an account and got stuck.  Anyway figured out I could export the document as a PDF and get printouts. Thanks

Comment: I downvote your question because it lacks of effort

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Wine AppDB for MS Office 2010](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17336) (32-Bit) for running MS Office on your Ubuntu . Wine Version 1.5.13 or better is required for greater compatibility.
Although I'd recommend using Libre Office instead of MS as it's already installed and works as fine as MS .

Comment: I do use LibreOffice but when I am trying to get printouts of documents created using LibreOffice, the pages are scrambled. I installed Wine and PlayOnLinux. Can you please give the steps to install MS Office?

Comment: @Jay There are [a](http://www.maketecheasier.com/linux-howto-miss-your-windows-application-try-wine/) [few](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) [resources](http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games) [about](https://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?appId=31) [that](http://www.howtogeek.com/171565/how-to-install-microsoft-office-on-linux/). You should first try to do some search.

Comment: LibreOffice is ridiculously worse than MS Office, for many features. Also, it doesn't answer the original question but simply suggests a clearly inferior product.

Answer (score 0):

A sure solution is to use  a virtual machine with minimal winxp install using [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/download.html) & office 2003. Its is fast and with recent updates to VirtualBox it can be seamless.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest XP…

Comment: @LéoLam You don't have to put any network options active for XP making it a light weight option. But yeah... XP...

Answer (score 0):

They can not be installed in Ubuntu. using wine is a nightmare. If you insist using them I suggest install a windows in vbox and install them in windows there.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The best advice for when you can't run something on Ubuntu, is to just get yourself a Windows license and run it there. It's not worth the fight. Remember, your time is valuable, and chances are that any solution will be at best, sub-optimal, and at worst, unusable.