# How to download game on linux ubuntu from a CD

Tags: games, downloads, cd

So I have a Bookworm Adventures CD and earlier today when I put it in, all I get are files. Nothing to install. Nothing to even play. I've been searching for hours please help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the CD must be having .exe application test if its Linux supported.
try navigating to the cd and typing

```
./configure
make
make install
```

If its Linux supported this wil do the trick or else you'll have to google for the linux version of the software

Comment: Oh alright thanks I didn't know it was Windows only :-)

Answer (score 0):

Bookworm adventures is a windows game. You would need to either use windows or use an emulator like `wine`.

Comment: I already have the latest Wine

Comment: It is usually advisable to give as much info as possible when asking questions.  ie, what you have tried. What you know etc. Not only does this question have barely any information it is in fact a duplicate of

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games