# How to install Ansys15 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: software-installation

I am a novice in using Ubuntu.Can anyone guide me through the process to install Ansys 15 in Ubuntu14.04 LTS? I have the ANSYS software on the CD.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows software or games?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at is manual: http://saiwal.esy.es/tech/installing-ansys-15-in-ubuntu-14-04/