# What will happen with my windows based games?

Tags: windows, games

I am planning on installing Ubuntu but I'm not sure if the windows based games that i already have will carry over (ex. Battlefield 4, Call Of Duty Advanced Warfare, and Grand Theft Auto 5)

Comment: In general, Linux is not a drop in replacement for Windows and your windows apps, including games, will not run

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows software or games?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for every game, but [wine](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/wine1.4/) is a tool which you can use to execute some of the windows based applications and games.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a gamer. I decided to set my system to dual boot. I already had a SSD drive that wasn't being used so, I put the Ubuntu disk image onto a flash drive and used the installer to create the partition for the OS and a partition for the swap file and told the installer to put the boot loader on the Ubuntu drive then, went into my BIOS and set it to the Ubuntu drive as #1 boot priority and the windows drive to #2 boot priority then saved and exited. If you do it this way you can still run your games without having to emulate windows with wine (slower). Also, if you install like this, don't forget to eject and remove the flash drive prior to trying to boot to the Ubuntu drive ;)

Answer (score 0):

In geenral no, but instead you can use some applications that run `.exe` files from inside Ubuntu, such as `wine`, `playonlinux` ....

The most known is [wine](https://www.winehq.org).

you can install wine using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Once wine is installed you can create a Windows environment inside your Ubuntu so you can install and use some windows app inside.

[Here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&sTitle=Browse%20Applications&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=true) you can find lits of apps that works with wine.

Another Option to use [Virtual machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) such as:

- Xen
- VBox
- Qemu
- VMWare

Here you can find a [list of available virtual machines for Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualMachines).

Now back for your question, here result of your needed games within wine:

- [Battlefield will work under wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1370)
- [Call Of Duty Advanced Warfare works great](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5934)
- [Grand Theft Auto 5 is not working yet](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=16807) but [Grand Theft Auto 4 works great](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=8757)