# How do I use wine after installing it?

Tags: wine

I fixed my issue I had with the error messages about wine but I dont know what I need to do after I have wine installed

Comment: please read the community wiki for wine. Installing windows applications with wine is explained in the wiki. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows software or games?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Answer (score 3):

- Download your chosen windows file
- right-click, select 'open with' and choose wine.

To view installed programs, search for 'wine' in the dash and run 'Browse C: Drive' - which is the same as the C: drive in windows.