# How do I run windows version of steam with wine

Tags: 14.04, steam

How can I run the windows version of steam using wine. (i'm a little confused with all the cd commands and stuff)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows software or games?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Answer (score -1):

Well, good news is you apparently don't need wine to run steam in ubuntu, it is supported natively. Bad news is you will have to use one or two commands, so i am gonna guide you through the procedure.

First download steam deb file from [here](http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/archive/precise/steam_latest.deb)

After it is downloaded, place it to your desktop. After that open a terminal and put in following commands one by one.

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
```

After dpkg completes you will have steam installed and you can close terminal. Goodluck

Comment: This does not answer the question. If you want to play any games that you own in Steam, which are only available for Windows, then yes, you need to use the Windows version of Steam.

Comment: @dobbey You do present a good point. However it was my understanding that op wanted to install steam in most easy way to his linux installation. If he needs to install windows software using wine or playonlinux i am sure he will update his query and so will i update my answer too. Nonetheless thanks for your input.

Comment: The question pretty clearly asks how to run the windows version of steam using wine.

Comment: @dobey Op doesnt need to install steam through wine it is available natively for ubuntu, even official wiki  at valve developer suggests that here https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_under_Linux#Ubuntu

Comment: Yes, there is a native Steam for Linux. However, you cannot play Windows games purchased through Steam, using the Steam for Linux client. You must use the Windows client. This question is very clearly asking how to run the Windows version of Steam. And that is very clearly a duplicate of the suggested duplicate.

Comment: @dobey On that i agree, if op wants to run windows games he will have to use wine or playonlinux  for running them but for installing steam he doesnt have to go that way. And definitely if op looks at the duplicate or the wiki he will be able to do so on his own but i could understand that he is afraid commands as they are new concept to him.

Comment: Sorry I realized that almost all my games have steam play so I can download them on ubunt but thank you all so much for your feed back

Comment: @ODog its good you got your problem sorted. Do tell if you need help with something else too. Goodluck!