# Migrate form Windows 8.1 to Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, windows-8

I am a Linux noob and have got Win 8.1
I wanna change to Ubuntu (by "change" I mean get rid of Win and permanently use Ubuntu) while keeping all the data in my computer (Videos, Pictures and some movies) intact and accessible while using Ubuntu. I got a drive partition Windows C:, Local disk D:, Local Disk E: and a DVD RW Drive F:.

And is it possible to have some Windows applications up and running WHILE using Linux? (Like wordpad, excel, word, spreadsheet, database etc., you know for projects and stuff)

Comment: Its is possible to use some windows software using wine in Ubuntu or you can use Libre office which is also like MS office.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows software or games?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Answer (score 3):

> (by "change" I mean get rid of Win and permanently change to Ubuntu) while keeping all the data in my computer (Videos, Pictures and some movies) intact and accessible while using Ubuntu.

I would advice against this. If you want to keep your data and keep using a Windows formatted partition you will at some point need to fall back to Windows for maintenance of those partitions.

If you want to keep this data make a backup and format d:, e: etc into `ext4` so it is native Linux and restore that backup to the Linux versions of these folders.

Otherwise I would suggest you shrink the windows partition, create an unallocated partition and install Ubuntu into that. You will then have a system with 2 operating system (or a dual boot) and Ubuntu will happily let you use the Windows partitions to store and retrieve data from. That can be used to clear out your Windows partitions by moving your data to Ubuntu and then reformating those partition to a Linux version (`ext4`).

> Like wordpad, excel, word, spreadsheet, database etc., you know for projects and stuff)

If you want to keep hanging onto Windows: go dual boot. WINE is not worth your time.

Wordpad you do not need in itself as it is just a text editor. We got plenty that do a better job. Excel(=spreadsheet) and Word can be done with LibreOffice Calc and LibreOffice Writer. It is sort of the same but also a bit different (and some of the basic things are done differently so it can be annoying if you are used to Word). But the learning curve is not that difficult. Database: MySQL is the leading database and available. If you are familiar with Access the learning curve is not too difficult.

Again: I would advice to go dual boot. Get the hang of Ubuntu, get used to the software in Ubuntu, move your files over to Ubuntu, shrink Windows as much as possible and if you ever reach a moment where you can say "hey I do not need Windows anymore" remove it either from grub or actually from your system. 
Prepare for a disappointment but do your best to get the hang of Ubuntu. If you can not switch for whatever reason you can easily revert to Windows.

---

As an alternative you can also install Windows INSIDE Ubuntu using virtualization (with VMWare or VirtualBox). Works best with solid machine with lots of RAM though.

Answer (score 1):

Install Wine Application Loader

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

or you can find alternate software instead.
for text editor using leafpad

```
sudo apt-get install leafpad
```

for office suite, using libre office.

Also, you could find more about that... You will find more easy with Linux

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to take the plunge,

- create a LiveCD version of the Linux distribution you want to use.
  This allows you to test drive various 'flavours' and only requires the time to do it.
- move all data you want to keep to a separate partition.
  Installing will overwrite your drives (There are exceptions, but they don't apply to you right now.) If you are fuzzy on partition read enough until you think you understand.  It will make life easier.
- install Ubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Whateveruntu.
  I find a multi-partition installation gives more flexibility without the added drama, {Root(1),Home(2),Swap(3), or Root(1), Home(2), [data](3), Swap(4)}, more than that on a lone PC is playing with yourself.  Now you can switch distributions like you'd change clothes.
- check out the native Linux applications first to see what does the same job adequately, the same, or better than your applications in the Windows world.  Every distribution has a "notepad" equivalanvent.  Already mentioned is the LibreOffice for the suite of things you might consider for a project.

I do nothing specialized, so my application requirements are all met with open source applications **which you should contribute to in time/talent/or funding as best as you are able**  Gimp, Blender, Hugin are beyond my capabilities, and yet my SO wants the simplicity of Picasa.  It, or nearly all of 'it' is possible. Use Synaptic or *ubutu Software Manager until you realize CLI is faster and more fun.

Wine is for those who still find some Windows applications indispensable.  Most work, some flawlessly...others not so.  http://winehq.org for help, or someone else's experience. Installing Winetricks makes live easier.  Using PlayOnLinux for games and stuff I know nothing about.

Currently I don't use Wine.  I'm giving my brain a rest from trying/and failing/ to get SketchUp to run under multiple versions of either.

Occasionally nothing works.  [There is script](http://gdayii.ca) that just will not work on anything *not* Windows, for which there is a handy virtual machine.

Flat flip flies straight, tilted flip turns. Experiment (Frisbee instructions)

Comment: ({Root(1),Home(2),Swap(3), or Root(1), Home(2), [data](3), Swap(4)}, more than that on a lone PC is playing with yourself. Now you can switch distributions like you'd change clothes.)

Can you explain this part in noob language?

Comment: Ubiquity, the popular installer, requires the root `/` partition to be formatted.  If `/home` is mounted on another partition,  that partition does *not* need to be formated.  All the files, the personal configuration, everything that is *you*,  your data are in a filesystem that is preserved.   Typically, on a single user pc, there is no need for a `/boot` partition, a `/opt` optional 3rd party partition, except if you wan the entertainment.  Generally switching distros is uncomplicated, not 100% flawless depending on which switch. from and to.