# photoshop elements

Tags: photoshop

I would like to run Photoshop Elements 14 on my Ubuntu 15.10 laptop.  Has anyone had success in this?
I am olllddd Windows user (1985) and have finally saw the light.  New to ubuntu, but you can teach 'old dog' new tricks.
Any one have some help?
Thanks,
Jim941

Comment: Unfortunately, Adobe does not support Linux systems. You might want to try _gimp_ available in the software center as an alternative. It's open source and may fill your needs.

Comment: This may also interest you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games - but running Windows programs always is a bit of a hack. Do have a look at Gimp, IMO much better than PE.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 choices to get Photoshop Elements running in Ubuntu 15.10:

1. If your system has sufficient resources you could run it using Virtualbox. This is the best option I suspect.
2. You could set up a dual boot system of Windows and Ubuntu and run it as a native application under Windows.
3. You could attempt running it with Wine. Looks like older versions have [some success under Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1794).

A few choices to make there, I would run it under Virtualbox myself...