# Compatibility of existing software loaded on Wiondows PC

Tags: windows

I am currently thinking about moving from Windows to Linux.
I have many programs already on my PC but would like to know if they will still work on Linux.
They include;
Photoshop Elements
Lightroom
Google Earth
Serif Page Plus
Avira Pro AV
Chrome
Skype
Also My printer - Lexmark Colour Laser and an Epson Scanner among many

I am basically sick to the back teeth with Windows updates that take hours to complete and would love a simple alternative.  I am not, by the way, well versed in computer software.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Install Virtualbox in Windows and Ubuntu inside it. Get the hang of Ubuntu, try to find similar software to what you use on Windows and when you are satisfied install Ubuntu as a dual boot and see if you ever go back to Windows. And when you do remove it.

Comment: Most of these software are not available in Linux. Even the similar software cannot serve as those you mentioned. So, either consider installing Ubuntu in a Virtual machine as @Rinzwind suggested or install it alongside your windows.

Answer (score 1):

None of the programs are going to work by directly copying them over.  Instead, you'll want to learn if the software you want to use has versions available to Linux, or if there are alternatives you're can use.

While some of the programs you listed are available for Linux, some of them are not.  For example, you will have a hard time getting [Photoshop Elements](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729802/photoshop-elements) running.

Your best bet is to go to the official website of each software and try to find a Linux installer/download.  Otherwise, search the internet for `whatever linux` and see if there.  If it's not available, or if the solution to get it working seems daunting, try `linux alternatives to whatever`.

Even after you figure this out, you will need a plan to pull out the data for each software.  Chrome can store configuration in the cloud, but you don't want to lose any Photoshop files you've worked on.

---

Ubuntu and other Linux distributions often offer a [Live CD](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install).  This lets you load up Ubuntu and test it out without modifying your current setup.  Once you decide you want to go further, you can install it alongside Windows.  By doing this, you allow yourself the ability to go back to Windows when needed, and slowly bring down your dependency on Windows.  When you have the option of loading one or more operating systems, it's called [Dual Booting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).