# Speakonia on ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04

The Speakonia download on Cnet is an `.exe` file. I want to get speakonia on my computer without using `wine` unless I absolutely have to. Is there an Ubuntu version? I am running ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Unity desktop).

Comment: .exe is exclusively the extension of executable file for Windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows software or games?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you will need to use either wine or a virtualized Windows to use it.

Alternatives:

- [espeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/). There is a front-end called gespeaker in the repositories.
- [fala](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fala/) (gnome)
- [neospeech](http://www.neospeech.com/)

espeak can read out website but also files from command line. From the link:

> **Languages**.
>
> The eSpeak speech synthesizer supports several languages, however in many cases these are initial drafts and need more work to improve them. Assistance from native speakers is welcome for these, or other new languages. Please contact me if you want to help.
>
> eSpeak does text to speech synthesis for the following languages, some better than others.
>
> Afrikaans, Albanian, Aragonese, Armenian, Bulgarian, Cantonese, Catalan, Croatian, Czech, Danish, Dutch, English, Esperanto, Estonian, Farsi, Finnish, French, Georgian, German, Greek, Hindi, Hungarian, Icelandic, Indonesian, Irish, Italian, Kannada, Kurdish, Latvian, Lithuanian, Lojban, Macedonian, Malaysian, Malayalam, Mandarin, Nepalese, Norwegian, Polish, Portuguese, Punjabi, Romanian, Russian, Serbian, Slovak, Spanish, Swahili, Swedish, Tamil, Turkish, Vietnamese, Welsh.

Answer (score 2):

Speakonia is no longer supported by the creators, and is windows only.  So to get it to work you will have to use Wine, or find another TTS linux application.

Your options can be found here -- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TextToSpeech

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I encounter the exact same problem you are describing myself, one year ago, when switching to Ubuntu I tried different tools on Wine, but the setup was very difficult and not really working.

For this reason, I created a new TTS utility which could do exactly what you need. It works offline, for free with AI-based high-quality voice. You can you it everywhere: Firefox browser, PDF reader, chrome, LibreOffice, etc.

Feel free to have a look, I just created a video tutorial with installation steps and DEMO: https://youtu.be/hb1ZVwUcPCU

Download link and Project page: https://github.com/MattePalte/Verbify-TTS

Feel free to leave comment/open issue to discuss new ideas, problems or constructive criticism.

Hoping it will help you.