# Left 4 Dead 2 on Ubuntu

Tags: wine, games

I have a Left 4 Dead 2 Windows installer in exe. My other games were installed by "PlayOnLinux" app, but there is no L4D2 version, or any sign that it will be avaliable in the future. I also didn't find any ubuntu or even linux distribution of this game, although i know the tests were made.

So how to install it on Ubuntu with exe installer? Will Wine be just fine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows software or games?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Comment: L4D2 has a [native Linux version](http://store.steampowered.com/app/550/) that I encourage you to try instead of going through Wine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will Wine be just fine?

Depending on the software you want to run, sometimes you as well need the package `winetricks`

Check the wine documentation for the game:
https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10546

There seem to be two basic ways of getting things to work. With steam and without steam. For the steam-version there is a Gold and a Platinum Test for Ubuntu, so it should run fine.

Answer (score 0):

Left 4 Dead 2 is out for Linux on steam? The native version performs really well, and is far easier to use than to try to use the windows version in wine.