# Software installation through command line from download folder

Tags: command-line

I have just installed ubuntu 16 along with window 7 and also new for ubuntu. I have downloaded some software with .zip, .tar and .exe format which are in downloads folder. Kindly suggest me how to install them from command line.

Comment: For `.exe` files, you need to use Wine. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games.

Answer (score 0):

That's how you used to install stuff when using windows but not how software is typically installed on most linux systems.

Similar to android or osx, software is typically installed using the **Ubuntu Software Center** (equivalent: google play) or use `apt-get` on the command line. Software is not typically downloaded and then installed unless completely unavailable through the Ubuntu Software Center or `apt-get`

Also, these commands help:

```
sudo apt-get update
apt list
apt-cache search somesearchterm
```

Replace somesearchterm with an actual search term.

[See here for more info.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)