# Windows 10 Store Games on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: wine, games, steam, playonlinux

What I'm asking is if there is any way to install games from the Windows 10 Store on Ubuntu 16.04.

I know about PlayOnLinux, I know about Wine, but I cannot use them to install what I want.

The game is Bloons Tower Defense Battles or BTD Battles.
http://store.steampowered.com/app/444640/

I've also tried to install the Linux version of Steam but when I try to download it from the steam website, it says it's not supported on my OS.
I tried installing the Windows version of Steam using PlayOnLinux to try to fool the website but, that one has a problem with the in-app browser in Steam and it can't get to the game to download it. Launching the Steam from Chrome to directly install the game doesn't work either, it simply doesn't see Steam installed on the system (I'm talking about the emulated one of course)

So, any ideas? :D

Comment: You are aware that programs for Windows are completely incompatible with Linux? Linux doesn't even know what a .exe is. Games that work on Linux are specifically adjusted to that by the developers. If your game isn't ported to Linux, it can't run on Linux :) Edit: I see on Steam that it says "OS: Windows 7+", so you are probably out of luck.

Comment: It's not clear from your message if you have steam up and running on Ubuntu.  Can you verify if you do?

Comment: @L.D.James he does not. he only tried to install steam in wine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows software or games?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Comment: @Nearoo The OP's link shows he's trying to run the Windows 10 steampowered games and he's having problems with the steam that he has tried to install on his computer.   Steam games are not `.exe` files, per se.  I believe steam powered games are coded in `java`. (https://www.google.com/#q=what+are+steam+games+coded+in)  I believe the requisite for running them is `steam` which is natively supported on the Ubuntu platform.

Answer (score 1):

Steam is available in the Ubuntu repository distribution.  You can install it by running this from a terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install steam
```

Run `Steam` from `ubuntu`'s launch button.

You can find Bloons TD Battles in Steam's search menu.

[image]