# How do I download a Windows game on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, games

Is there any way to download this Windows 10 game on Ubuntu? The game is bloons tower defense battle or btd battles. Here is the game link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/bloons-td-battles/9nblggh6cwkl

Comment: Possible answer: http://superuser.com/questions/502203/is-there-a-way-to-run-windows-8-apps-on-linux

Comment: Bloons TD on Steam: https://askubuntu.com/a/821779/114641

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The game you linked is on the Windows 10 App Store.  There is no way to use the Windows 10 app store on Ubuntu nor apps from that store on Ubuntu.

There may be a web browser version of this game on the [Bloons TD people's Site (NinjaKiwi)](https://ninjakiwi.com/) that doesn't need the app store to use, but it may not operate on the same "multiplayer" environment as the Windows 10 app does, and it might need you to register a NinjaKiwi account to get it to store progress, though I am not certain of this (I think it might be [this link](https://ninjakiwi.com/Games/Tower-Defense/Bloons-TD-Battles.html) for a standard web browser version of the game but can't check this or the need for an account easily from my phone)