# Install windows software on Ubuntu 16.04lts

Tags: dual-boot, software-center, hp

I'm a newbie user. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 lts on this afternoon.

I'd like to know if it's possible to install, on ubuntu 16.04lts, some software I had specifically suited for windows.
--> Does any app exist that can make this job?

My PC:
- HP media center PC m7000 (year 2007)
- operating system: dual boot "windows vista" & "ubuntu 16.04lts"

Issue:
I noticed that "Ubuntu software" doesn't work anymore, so, if the app existed I couldn't download it from the Ubuntu software. How could I possibly cope with it?

best regards!
Papillon

Answer (score 1):

Yes, software to run Windows applications does exist, its called Wine. It's available in the Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic Package Manager.

They have rather large support for Windows applications, but some aren't compatible yet.

- [Wine Homepage](https://www.winehq.org/)
- [Wine Installation Guide](https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/getting-wine)

Regarding Ubuntu Software Center not working anymore, you could try

```
sudo apt-get update
```

in a terminal (open using Ctrl + Alt + T).

Answer (score 0):

for using Windows software you can use WINE, open your terminal by `Ctrl+Alt+T` then enter these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine
```

If apt-get complains about missing dependencies, install them, then repeat the last two steps (update and install).

Or Check this quick tuto on [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Windows-Programs-in-Ubuntu) .

For more read:

- Answers on [How can I install Windows software or games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)
- [WineHQ Wiki](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)

About your "Software Center" this solution should fix it:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install --only-upgrade gnome-software
```

Or intall the old Software Center :

```
sudo apt install software-center
```