# How Can I Install Office 365 and AVG Without Using Virtual Machine on Linux/Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, microsoft-office

I'm planning to soon switch to Linux/Ubuntu, but I need to know if there's anyway to install Office 365 without using VM software.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows software or games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Answer (score 2):

Installing Windows application on Ubuntu is surely not the best way to work. You can try **wine** and **[playonlinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/)** as Office 2013 seems officially supported. Wine website indicate that [it's possible to install Office 2016](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=35527), but it's a little bit tricky.

Some very nice alternative are existing of you don't want to use Microsoft Office. You can try [WPS Office](http://wps-community.org/) that give a similar look and good compatibility with Office documents.

Regarding AVG, it's definitely not a good idea. Antivirus have a deep implication with the operating system, and will be probably not possible to be installed with wine anyway. You should choose a native antivirus like [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/), but it will be more useful to avoid passing virus to other Windows computers than protecting Ubuntu.

Comment: I see many other people have AVG for Linux. Did AVG stop making the Linux version?

Answer (score 2):

I got Office 365 by going to the web version of each app in Chromium, then going to Settings > More Tools > Add to Desktop.  Make sure 'Open as window' is checked.  You'll get a shortcut on your desktop that you can put anywhere and it opens like an app.  Got Outlook and Excel working no problem, I assume the others will be the same if I need them.

Comment: Those are indeed the web versions, not the full apps that OP wants to install.

Comment: It's better than nothing and work great for me, just a thought.