# How do I install Filmora video editing software on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, video-editor

I want to install Filmora video editing software on my Ubuntu GNOME 17.04.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know it doesn't support GNU/Linux. You may try using [Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games) to install the Windows version, but I'm not really hopeful that it would work properly under Ubuntu.

You may look into some alternatives to work with Ubuntu:

- [OpenShot](http://www.openshot.org/)
- [Pitivi](http://www.pitivi.org/)
- [Shortcut](https://www.shotcutapp.com/)
- [kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/)
- [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/)

etc.

Comment: Can you pls told me the whole processes??

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/989/
Also see the alternatives I have suggested.

Comment: you can try some other software to see if it fits your needs

There are pretty cool video editors that natively works in Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for the references to alternatives. Can you also comment on each one, to help us choose?