# How does one get a .exe file to run?

Tags: 14.04, wine

How would someone get a `.exe` file on Ubuntu to run? Because my wine just isn't working. Can you run a `.exe` file through terminal or not? I have just tried double clicking it but wine doesn't seem to like to run with my geometry dash.exe file.

Comment: Try PlayOnLinux maybe https://askubuntu.com/a/262123/295286

Answer (score 3):

> How would someone get a .exe file on ubuntu to run?

You don't.

WINE is a compatibility layer that enables to mimic Windows in a separate environment. Your question should be "How would someone get a .exe file in WINE to run?" and that answer is impossible to provide by us: there is no 1 way to run an .exe in WINE that works for all .exe files that are out there.

Specific to GeometryDash.exe.

- [WineHQ only has a gold rating for 14.04](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=16966).
- And there is a [page](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32376) dedicated to getting it run.

That will be all you have to go on.

If you need to run Windows executable I myself would install Windows either as a dual boot or inside a virtual container.

Answer (score 0):

You really can't run a Windows .exe file in Ubuntu... however...

Wine is a poor Windows compatibility layer, and although it works for some games/etc, it really isn't very good, and should probably be uninstalled, unless you have apps that do work with it.

The solution is to install VirtualBox. Install the Windows OS of your choice into a Virtualbox VM (*virtual machine*). Copy the .exe into your Windows VM desktop, or setup Shared Folders, to run your .exe.

Comment: Seems a bit unfair to call Wine poor, it certainly works better performance-wise than any VB and doesn't use as much space as them.

Comment: @creativiii except that Wine requires almost every app to use tweaks or modification to run. Virtualbox with a Windows Guest is 100% compatible.

Comment: Yes programs require to be installed together with components that might be missing, all the info for these is found on WineHQ. It's still less hassle than setting up a VM.

Comment: @creativiii We'll just have to agree to disagree. Setting up a VB VM w/Windows takes minutes, and apps don't require mods to run.