# EF file extension

Tags: filesystem, password

How can I open Easy-firmware's EF file extension? The tool they provide is windows only and they will not provide a supposed password to open in Linux. They started this crap extension after I had paid for membership and now I can't access the files I've purchased. I say supposed password because their "tool" is for opening their own EF firmware files with EF.ext without password. It's like they're hacking their own stuff or incapable of maintaining a password system. Help with an opening solution would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games

Answer (score 0):

Linux does NOT have "file extensions offering type information", like Windows (remember the `foo.pdf.exe` bug?).

Linux filenames can contain any ASII character, except `NUL` and `/`, and, if they hint at a file's contents (`foo.c`), they do so only by convention.

Filenames with special characters in them require careful handling in scripts.

Handily, some Linux tools produce or accept lists of filenames with `NUL` (`000`) between filenames. Some are:

```
du - estimate file space usage
find - search for files in a directory hierarchy
grep, egrep, fgrep, rgrep - print lines matching a pattern
perl - Practical Extraction and Report Language
shuf - generate random permutations 
sort sort - sort lines of text files
uniq uniq - report or omit repeated lines
xargs - build and execute command lines from standard input
xz ,  unxz, xzcat, lzma, unlzma, lzcat - Compress or decompress .xz and .lzma files
modinfo - program to show information about a Linux Kernel module
```

Finally, try `file foo.EF` (if it says `data`, you're probably out of luck). Other tools that may let you look at the data in the file are `strings foo.EF`, and `od -bc foo.EF`.

You could also install `wine` (start with `apt-cache search wine` and go from there), and see if their tool runs under `wine`.