# .exe downloads will not open to install. My laptop is new

Tags: software-installation

I am able to download the .exe files but I cannot open or install on Ubuntu.

Advice please.

My laptop is 1 day old

Comment: Wow, .exe files are "executable files" in Windows/MS-DOS operating systems, you probably are new in linux, you need to change in mind, that in linux, "executable files" are not the same as you are used until yesterday.

Comment: Note, that the answer selected as solution in the linked duplicate is a way to install Windows Software in Linux. Wine Emulation is nice and might work, but in general you should check if there is not a Linux-native solution to what you want to install or achieve. For most tasks, you simply don't need Windows Software. Better check the [second answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/262123/631600) of the linked question first.