# Is it possible to install Microsoft Whiteboard on Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, wine, playonlinux, microsoft

I downloaded the latest version installation file of Microsoft Whiteboard on https://www.filehorse.com/download-microsoft-whiteboard/

Using Playonlinux and choosing in the folder *64 the subfile  *.exe ,playonlinux was not able to install.

Is there a method that can install this app? Is there an older version of Microsoft Whiteboard that is installable on Linux?

(Using Ubuntu 20.04)

Note: This is not about openboard (which has some excellent functionalities) thx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Windows software or games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games).  The short answer is "No", you cannot install Windows software.  The long answer is "Maybe, but it's complicated". Wine is not a panacea and every software is different. Search/research to see if anyone else has gotten this software to run successfully. Otherwise, consider running Windows in a VM

Comment: I found the executable file in may case WhiteboardWRT.exe. The link above mention using Trello example to " just run wine Trello.exe inside the app directory". I suppose that I have to go first in the directory using the Termnal  then run in my case "wine WhiteboardWRT.exe" . If yes, what command to use to reach to the directory.