# How to install 64 bit exe in playonlinux

Tags: wine, 64-bit, playonlinux

I wan to ask that how can we install 64 bit software using playonlinux.

when I enter this code in my terminal

```
playonlinux OdaClass-3.0.2-setup.exe
```

I get to see setup and when I try to install setup it shows me that

```
this setup is 64-bit and try installing 32-bit installer
```

system information

> ```
>   version - 20.04 64-bit
>
>   OS      - Ubuntu 20.04
>
>   software trying to install `OdaClass-3.0.2-setup.exe`
> ```

please help me out and Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Linux you’re running (1) the name of the software you are trying to install. With this, it may be possible to offer an answer 

Comment: I am trying to install `OdaClass-3.0.2-setup.exe`

Comment: Without knowing more about which version of Ubuntu you’re running, it will be difficult for anyone to offer a reasonable answer. If you’re using a 32-bit version of the OS, for example, then the answer is very different than if you are running a more recent version 

Comment: Alright please help me out now

Comment: Please first review: https://askubuntu.com/q/988 Wine and Playonlinux are not a one-size-fits-all solution to running Windows software on Linux. Many applications simply won't or can't work this way. You really need to dig into the particulars about the specific software you are trying to run. Start by telling us the name of the software and also where you obtained it.  It would be good to research if anyone else has already documented how to install this particular software.