# how to install gv50m.exe onto ubuntu 22.04 and run the program using wine-stable

Tags: wine, executable

The .exe is a installation file for a gps tracker management and update software, i cant seem to figure out how to do it. Please let me know what system information is needed (and how to obtain such info) as i am a bit of a noob at Linux. I am currently running Ubuntu 22.04 Thanks.,
Also ive installed winehq-devel 3.01 i believe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Windows software or games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Comment: You  start on the Wine support site to see if the app is even possible to run with Wine.