# How can I install Windows games from a .exe file?

Tags: apt, kernel, sudo

I download a game with a .exe file name and I can't install it and so a ppsspp game emulator with also a .exe file name. So how can I go about it.

Answer (score 0):

.exe files are executables written for Windows. Generally speaking you can’t execute a Windows program directly within Ubuntu (or any other os).

Check if the game supports Linux - there sometimes is a Linux version (eg Minecraft). Steam - where you can access a lot of windows games - is available in Linux. If not, and you want a particular game, there are options but they’re a bit unsatisfactory in my view.

Have a look at this question and the answers: [How can I install Windows software or games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

My experience is that Linux / Ubuntu is great for general use and many applications have a Linux equivalent, but for gaming especially, it can be difficult as the software is proprietary and an equivalent / alternative is often not good enough.

Lastly, please take a look here https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask  - it’s much easier to offer help if you add some more information to your question.